# generate different color for marker type

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I use google markers for my google map. Each marker has a different color depending on the type you define like this:

```
var customIcons = {
      1: {
      icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|ED0000"

      },
      2: {
      icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|F7FF3C"

      }
```

I've created a mysql table named "colors" which contains 2 columns: id and color_cod . In my color_cod i put color codes like this: `ED0000` ;

What I want is to get the code colors from my table and put them in a for and for each value from 1 to 100 get different code color. Something like this:

```
$a=mysql_query("select color_cod from colors where id='$id'")
$b=mysql_fetch_array($a);
```

This is the php part and now I would want in the javascript part something like this:

```
var i=0;

for(i=0;i<=100;i++)

{

  var customIcons = {

      i: {
      icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|$b['color_cod']"


      }

}
```

Something like this I would want to get. Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: So what is it you can't work out?

Comment: What is it that is not working? I see you have a loop to add your customIcons.

Comment: if I put the loop that way the map isn't showing...so I don't know how to make that loop in order to work..